# Send Email is disabled or activities are not allowed. Enable Send Email and allow activities, then try again

Tags: deployment, salesforce-id, deployment-api

I'm getting the following error while deploying the case page layout to another org vi **Copado**.

**Deployment Error:**

```
[QuickAction Case.Custom_Email] Send Email is disabled or activities are not allowed. Enable Send Email and allow activities, then try again.[Layout Case-Billing Line Item Adjustment] In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named Case.Custom_Email found
```

In target org I did the "**No Access**" for **Deliverability**  under the **Email Administration** and tried to deploy the page layout still getting the same error.

Kindly please help me out.

Comment: In target org I given the "All email" for Access level under Deliverability and validating but still getting the same error

Comment: Does your page layout have Activity related list?

Comment: No I don't have Activity related list on the page layout

Comment: Please add the related list and also make sure the 'Send Email' button is there

Comment: I added the related list Activity History, Open Activities, and Emails to my new case page layout, But still getting the same error. Kindly please let me know If I'm missing any other components to my copado user story.

In target org I have given the "All email" for Access level under Deliverability.

Comment: Copado has a great support forum. Have you tried posting there?

Comment: I ran into similar issues with a Service Cloud migration - I set up the Email-to-Case settings and the org-wide email addresses in the target org and this squashed the issues. rt

Comment: Did you add the Close Email quick action to your Copado package?

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this same message when using SFDX to deploy the QuickAction:SendEmail in my QA sandbox (which was cloned from Production).

The fix for me was going to Setup > Deliverability, and changing Access Level to "All email". After making that change, my sfdx force:source:deploy worked normally.

It looks like that didn't work for you above (back on August 10'19), but noting it here for other SFDX users who may stumble upon this issue now. It worked for my case.

Answer (score 0):

For Case Emails...

1. Ensure the Deliverability is set to All Email
2. Enable Email-to-Case (and enable on demand if required),create routing address and verify
3. Ensure the org wide default email address is setup and verified.
4. Ensure the Open Activities and Activity History is on layout and can't hurt to ensure the Email (SendEmail) action is on the layout.
5. Ensure the profile has the Send Email permission